# AWS API Gateway Lambda Error Regex

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have Lambda function written in Python 2.7 which is triggered from API Gateway,

I want API Gateway to return 400 code when Lambda fails and I don't want to use Lambda Proxy so I'm trying to set API Gateway Integration Response.

When Lambda function fails it returns:

```
{
    "stackTrace": [
        [
            "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
            12,
            "lambda_handler",
            "raise Exception('failure')"
        ]
    ],
    "errorType": "Exception",
    "errorMessage": "failure"
}
```

Lambda Error Regex and Body Mapping template:
[image]

..the same from CLI:

```
aws apigateway get-integration-response --rest-api-id bz47krygwa --resource-id 788q0w --http-method ANY --status-code 400 --region us-west-1
{
    "statusCode": "400",
    "selectionPattern": ".*\"failure\".*",
    "responseTemplates": {
        "application/json": "#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$.errorMessage'))\n$inputRoot"
    }
}
```

..but it doesn't work correctly and still returns 200 code:
[image]

any advice on fix please?

Answer (score 6):

Answer turned out to be very simple - removing double quotes from Lambda Error Regex did the trick,

moreover Body Mapping template could also be removed:
[image]

..and it works as expected:
[image]