# Wrong error returned when using AWS Api Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function written in Java which is triggered in API Gateway.

I want that the API Gateway to return 400 code when Lambda fails so I'm trying to set API Gateway Integration Response.

This in an example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeQMi.png)

This how I have the configuration of the API Gateway:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uzLO.png)

What I pretend with this configuration, is to set the value of errorMessage in errorMessage, and I set the "Lambda Error Regex" with the expression An error.

Since the value of errorMessage is "An error ocurred during JSON parsing", the regular expression matched and 400 status should be returned.

But As you can see, It's not working like that and it still returns 201 code.

Any advice on fix please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50152220/aws-api-gateway-lambda-error-regex

Comment: Excellent. It worked (in AWS tests). Do you know why in Postman it still shows 201?

Comment: In Google Chrome ARC (Advanced Rest client), I see the same 201 code.